# Program doesn't run after DFU

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32f4, dfu

I am trying to run a blink LED program on my [STM32F401CCU6 board](https://robu.in/product/stm32f401ccu6-minimum-system-board-microcomputer-stm32-arm-core-board/), and I am using basic CLI tools (in Linux) like `arm-none-eabi-gcc` or `dfu-util` (or `openocd`) for learning purposes.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://kleinembedded.com/stm32-without-cubeide-part-1-the-bare-necessities/) to create the basic program, with one change. I do not have ST-Link, and am trying to use the USB-C port that comes with the board for flashing (and thus, using `dfu-util`). It does not rely on any STM header files (except `stdint.h`, which is for `uint32_t`, and is also from the compiler).

The command I used to upload this is:

```bash
$ dfu-util -a 0 -s 0x08000000:leave -D ./main.elf
dfu-util 0.11

Copyright 2005-2009 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc.
Copyright 2010-2021 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt
This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Please report bugs to http://sourceforge.net/p/dfu-util/tickets/

dfu-util: Warning: Invalid DFU suffix signature
dfu-util: A valid DFU suffix will be required in a future dfu-util release
Opening DFU capable USB device...
Device ID 0483:df11
Device DFU version 011a
Claiming USB DFU Interface...
Setting Alternate Interface #0 ...
Determining device status...
DFU state(10) = dfuERROR, status(10) = Device's firmware is corrupt. It cannot return to run-time (non-DFU) operations
Clearing status
Determining device status...
DFU state(2) = dfuIDLE, status(0) = No error condition is present
DFU mode device DFU version 011a
Device returned transfer size 2048
DfuSe interface name: "Internal Flash  "
Downloading element to address = 0x08000000, size = 9528
Erase           [=========================] 100%         9528 bytes
Erase    done.
Download        [=========================] 100%         9528 bytes
Download done.
File downloaded successfully
Submitting leave request...
Transitioning to dfuMANIFEST state
```

[This](https://pastebin.com/uESA2DHW) is the objdump of `main.elf`.

However, both the on-board LED and the LED connected to A5 pin do not glow. I even tried switching the code to point to the C13 on-board LED, but still it does not glow.

I got this `dfu-util` from the AUR.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the code in a while(1) hardware fault handler? If you don't have a debugger, developing things that utilize DFU is...difficult at best. It also mentions corrupt firmware. And then it says it flashed correctly. It's confusing. How about this: put your blinky code inside default interrupt handler. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Ilya It has an exact same output.

Comment: So it doesn't even get there. Interesting. Recently, there was a question here, where there was something similar when linker script sections were empty. Try adding one initialized global variable and one uninitialized global variable, so you have something in both .data and .bss. Does it even boot from flash and not from system bootloader? You can also put the entire blinky code into the startup. In fact, you can remove all loads from startup if you have no global vars. You really need a debugger. Without one, all you can do is poke stuff and see if anything changes.